# Details of Stage in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to save `DataFrame` as text file in `HDFS` using `spark-shell`.

```
scala> finalDataFrame.rdd.saveAsTextFile(targetFile)
```

After executing the above code I found spark internally doing some work using stages.

> [Stage 13:================================>                     (119 +
>   8) / 200]

I am trying to understand the basic details of this process. But not able to do so.
Here my questions are -

1. What is **Stage 13**?
2. What is **(119+8)/200**?

> [Stage 18:=============>(199 + 1) / 200][Stage 27:============> (173 +
>   3) / 200]

1. Here what is the meaning of this line.
2. Previously only 1 stage was working, but here I can found 2 stages are working. Hence when multiple stage are working in parallel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Stage 13:================================> (119 + 8) / 200]
>
> 1. What is Stage 13?

Each Spark job is divided into stages. The job in this case is the saving of a DataFrame as a text file, and "stage 13" is one of the multiple stages for that job.

> 2. What is (119+8)/200?

Examining the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala#L82) can help answer this:

```
val bar = stages.map { s =>
  val total = s.numTasks()
  val header = s"[Stage ${s.stageId()}:"
  val tailer = s"(${s.numCompletedTasks()} + ${s.numActiveTasks()}) / $total]"
  ...
}.mkString("")
```

Each stage is divided into tasks. `119` is the number of completed tasks for this stage (i.e., stage 13), `8` is the number of active tasks for this stage, and `200` is the total number of tasks for this stage.

> [Stage 18:=============>(199 + 1) / 200][Stage 27:============> (173 + 3) / 200]
>
> 1. Here what is the meaning of this line.
> 2. Previously only 1 stage was working, but here I can found 2 stages are working. Hence when multiple stage are working in parallel?

Again, looking at the source code ([here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala#L28) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala#L70)) is useful:

```
/** ...If multiple stages run in the same time, the status
 *  of them will be combined together, showed in one line.
 */

...

if (stages.length > 0) {
  show(now, stages.take(3))  // display at most 3 stages in same time
}
```

The stages run concurrently, so within the window of time during which the progress bar is refreshed, multiple stages may be running. In this case, stages 18 and 27 are running at the same time. The code limits the display to three simultaneously running tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you please let me know how Spark internally divides a job into multiple stages and stage into multiple tasks. How Spark decided the no of stages and tasks.